# Loop over a NSDictionary with swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I don't understand why this piece of Objective-C code:

```
id object = nil;
NSEnumerator *enumerator = ...;
while ((object = [enumerator nextObject])) {...}
```

can't be translated in Swift like this:

```
var key:AnyObject!
let enumerator:NSEnumerator = myNSDictionary.keyEnumerator()    
while ( (object = enumerator.nextObject()) ) {...}
```

I have this error :

> Type '()' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **Objective-C,** `[enumerator nextObject]` returns an *object pointer*
which is `nil` when when all objects have been enumerated,
and the value of an assignment

```
object = [enumerator nextObject]
```

is equal to the assigned value. In

```
while ((object = [enumerator nextObject])) { ... }
```

the while-block is executed as long as the expression compares
unequal to 0, where 0 in this case is the *null pointer constant* which is usually written as `NULL`, or `nil` for Objective-C pointers. So that
loop is equivalent to

```
while ((object = [enumerator nextObject]) != nil) { ... }
```

In **Swift,** an assignment does not have a value (it is a `Void`),
therefore

```
while ( (object = enumerator.nextObject()) )
```

does not compile. You can forcibly cast it to a `BooleanType`
to make it compile but that will crash at runtime.

`enumerator.nextObject()` returns `AnyObject?`, i.e. an
*optional* object, which is `nil` when all objects have been enumerated. The proper way to test the return value for `nil` is
*optional binding*:

```
let enumerator = myNSDictionary.keyEnumerator()
while let key = enumerator.nextObject() {
    print(key)
}
```

(Of course, bridging the `NSDictionary` to a Swift `Dictionary`
and then using the Swift enumeration methods, as suggested in the
other answer, is a sensible alternative.)

Answer (score 9):

You should enumerate over a dictionary as follows (which is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105) in further detail):

**Test dictionary declaration:**

```
var airports = ["YYZ": "Toronto Pearson", "DUB": "Dublin"]
```

**Enumerate both key and value:**

```
for (airportCode, airportName) in airports {
    print("\(airportCode): \(airportName)")
}
// YYZ: Toronto Pearson
// LHR: London Heathrow
```

**Enumerate just keys:**

```
for airportCode in airports.keys {
    print("Airport code: \(airportCode)")
}
// Airport code: YYZ
// Airport code: LHR
```

**Enumerate just values:**

```
for airportName in airports.values {
    print("Airport name: \(airportName)")
}
// Airport name: Toronto Pearson
// Airport name: London Heathrow
```

Maybe there was a deeper reason you are choosing to use `NSEnumerator`, but if not the above is alot more elegant from a Swift point of view.

Comment: You're right but I needed to understand why this error appeared when translating 'strictly'. Thanks for your answer.